# The most elegant way to divide the array into subarrays by criteria

Tags: java, arrays

**I've got:** Very big array: {o1, o2, o3, ..., o100000}. There are situations when sequence of elements has the same field value. I mean `o1.getField()` equals `o2.getField()` equals `o3.getField()`. Lets say o1, o2 and o3 are ***similar***.

**I want:** Proceed some postaction on each of similar elements subarray (eg. `{o1, o2, o3}`, `{o4, o5}`,...).

**It's important:** Due array is very big, caching (means moving array to another collection or coppying part of it) is unacceptable!

**Question:** What is the most elegant way of doing so?

**P.S.** I have no need to divide the whole array and only than make an postAction. I can get the first one `{o1, o2, o3}`, make postAction, than get the second one and so on...

Comment: Top of my head... caching indices of similar objects on a linked HashMap

Comment: @gtgaxiola caching impose performance overhead.

Comment: Caching of indices, not of the contents. And you could maybe identify the relevant indices through a Divide-And-Conquer-Algorithm.

Comment: oh the old time vs space tradeoff...

Comment: @gtgaxiola my bad. I change the question. The final purpose isn't to divide an array. The final purpose is to make an postAction on each of similar elements subarrays

Comment: I'm guessing the subarrays can be big too?

Comment: Yes, but I mean logical subarrays. You have no need to create a separate array for each of them. Just do postAction for each "similar" segment of array

Comment: Do you have to iterate over all n elements to find the sequences? Then you have to keep track of boundaries which in the worst case would divide your array into n-subarrays.

Comment: I would have said to use Multiset Discrimination, but it isn't in place and would involve creating new arrays/lists.

Comment: What does "elegant" mean here?

Comment: @gtgaxiola no i shouldn't iterate through all the n elements. If `o5` isn't similar to `o6` that means the sequencefinished

Comment: @djechlin means as much clear and brief  code as possible

Answer (score 1):

I would start by challenging the "the array can't be copied" premise. Array copying is extremely fast if you use [`System.arrayCopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)!

Here's a little sample program I wrote that creates, fills and copies an array of 100,000,000 elements.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    final Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch().start();
    final String[] arr = new String[100_000_000];
    Arrays.fill(arr, "foo");

    final String[] arr2 = new String[arr.length];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr2, 0, arr.length);
    stopwatch.stop();
    System.out.println(stopwatch.elapsed(MILLISECONDS));

}
```

On my non-impressive machine, this takes 683 milliseconds.

1. Is this unacceptable, given that the code will probably be running on a much faster machine than mine?
2. Or are your arrays significantly larger than 100000000 elements?

If neither of these is a yes, I'd go with some copying solution.

Comment: I don't need subarrays. They are logical instance, on which I should perform postAction. So I'm not sure if I must copy something at all

Comment: @VolodymyrBakhmatiuk granted. I was just challenging your premise, not offering a solution

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are working on objects of type `T` and have a method `isSimilar(T o1, T o2)`.
I am also assuming you have a class `Processor<T>` with a method `postAction(Iterator<T> i)` (can be adapted to `postAction(Iterable<T> i)`).

Then I would go along something of those lines. It is only a direction, unfortunately I don't have anything with me to test or even compile.

```
public <T>  void process(T[] array, Processor<T> p) {
  for (int i=0, j=1; i<array.length && j<array.length; i=j, j++) {
    while (j<array.length && isSimilar(array[i], array[j])) {
      j++;
    }
    ArrayIterator<T> ai = new ArrayIterator<T>(array, i, j-1);
    p.postAction(ai);
  }
}

class ArrayIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
  T[] array;
  int current;
  int end;

  public ArrayIterator(T[] a, int s, int e) {
    array = a;
    current = s;
    end = e;
  }

  public boolean hasNext() {
    return current <= end;
  }

  public T next() {
    return array[current++];
  }
}
```

If `postAction` takes a `List` or other imposed collection, you can create such a collection backed up by the array, like `Arrays.asList()`, but it will be more boiler-plate code. If `postAction` takes an array, I think you have to copy...

Answer (score 1):

we have this class

```
public static class MisteriousItem {

    public int oddlyFamiliarValue;

    public MisteriousItem(int oddlyFamiliarValue) {
        this.oddlyFamiliarValue = oddlyFamiliarValue;
    }

}
```

which we use to put in array:

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    MisteriousItem[] magicBox = new MisteriousItem[1_000];
    for (int i = 0; i < magicBox.length; i++) {
        magicBox[i] = new MisteriousItem(rand.nextInt(3));
    }
```

then we preparing few value

```
    List<Entry<Integer, String>> something;
    something = new ArrayList<>();

    MisteriousItem x = magicBox[0];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
    sb.append(x.oddlyFamiliarValue);
    int id = 0;
```

i know you said no copy, but this isn't part of an alogithm it is just that something to do with familiar objects

now we iterate

```
    for (int i = 1; i < magicBox.length; i++) {
        MisteriousItem mi = magicBox[i];
        if (mi.oddlyFamiliarValue == x.oddlyFamiliarValue) {
            sb.append(",");
            sb.append(id++);
        } else {
            sb.append("}");
            something.add(new Entry<>(x.oddlyFamiliarValue, sb.toString()));
            x = mi;
            sb = new StringBuilder("{");
            sb.append(id++);
        }
    }
```

as you can see, we are taking first object and start processing, then iterate over whole array starting from second item, and before doing anything, we are checking if it is similar to previous object. then we act accordingly to result of that comparing.
If you are looking some more elegant way, leave a comment and say what should be different.

**EDIT**

maybe this is more you are looking for

```
    int end=0;
    int start= 1;
    MisteriousItem x = magicBox[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < magicBox.length; i++) {
        MisteriousItem mi = magicBox[i];
        if (mi.oddlyFamiliarValue == x.oddlyFamiliarValue) {
            end++;
        } else {
            process(magicBox,start,end);
            //process lost starting from start(inclusive) to end(exclusive)
            start=i;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In-place sort on `getField` then sequentially iterate, only calling the action if `getField` changes. I believe this is the only solution that doesn't create the overhead of an array of the same length (since any other solution I can think of involves some mechanism to keep track of which `getField` values you have used).